# getting error connection failed in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

When i try to run command mongo from putty, it give me below error, can anyone please help me, how to resolve this error ?

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2019-01-17T04:29:27.984-0500 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1                                                                                        :27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2019-01-17T04:29:27.984-0500 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to ser                                                                                        ver 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Comment: show me the mongodb.log

Comment: Where can we find its log ?

Comment: in my case C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\log

Comment: I checked there is no log file

Comment: Check where the MongoDB installed in your system, find the log file, also is this the first instance you are try to make connection ?

Comment: Make sure mongo daemon is running. Try first `mongod` then `mongo`.